# Is it possible to capture SIGWINCH in Java?

Tags: java, signals

I have a console application I would like to react to changes in terminal size. 
In Linux/UNIX this is done through the SIGWITCH signal:

SIGWINCH    28  Window change. The WINCH signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal changes size, for instance if you resize it in your window manager.  4.3 BSD, Sun
Source: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/signals.htm

In the Java SE documentation I can find information relative to most common signals, but there is no reference to SIGWINCH.
Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/handle-signals-and-exceptions.htm

Is it possible to capture such signal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use `sun.misc.Signal` and the static `handle` function:

```
jshell> import sun.misc.Signal;
jshell> Signal.handle(new Signal("WINCH"), s -> System.out.println(s.getName() + "(" + s.getNumber() + ")"));
```

If you resize the window, you'll see this handler being called.
Note that this is JVM specific, this was tested on `openjdk 16.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can not test it as I have this project not active right now.

Comment: `Signal is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release` Any other solution without using the deprecated package?